# Pygame rendering surface to screen without clearing the screen

Tags: python, pygame

When you click on a specific card it should appear above, when clicked again it should drop down below. Momentarily when you click on a card, it doesn't just move the card up, it basically duplicates the card.

This is the script:

```
from utilities import *
import pygame
import sys

def main():
    pygame.init()
    size = width, height = 1920, 1020
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
    screen.fill((10, 200, 100))

    def display_card(card):
        screen.blit(pygame.image.load(card.img), card.coordonates)

    game = MackaoGame("Test1", "Test2")
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()

            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1:
                game.change_card_status(pygame.mouse.get_pos())
        
        card_count = 0
        for player, deck in game.player_decks.items():
            new_cards = []
            for card in deck:
                card_image = pygame.image.load(card.img)
                card.make_coordonates((50 * card_count + 500, 500))
                if card.status == "selected":
                    card.coordonates[1] -= 100
                new_cards.append(card)
                card_count += 1
            game.player_decks[player] = new_cards

        for player, deck in game.player_decks.items():
            for card in deck:
                display_card(card)
        pygame.display.update()

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

This is the utilities file:

```
from random import sample
from PIL import Image

class Card:

    def __init__(self, num, symbol, img, status):
        self.num = num
        self.symbol = symbol
        self.img = img
        self.status = status
        with Image.open(img) as image:
            self.img_width, self.img_height = image.size
        self.coordonates = [0, 0]
        self.velocity = 0
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return "This card is a {num} of {symbol}.".format(num = self.num, symbol = self.symbol)
    
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if self.num == other.num and self.symbol == other.symbol:
            return True
        return False
    
    def make_coordonates(self, center):
        self.coordonates = [center[0] - self.img_width / 2, center[1] - self.img_height / 2]

class MackaoGame:
    def __init__(self, *players):
        self.players = players
        self.player_wait_times = {player: 0 for player in players}
        self.give_cards()
        self.card_debt = 0
        self.round = 0

    def make_deck(self):
        deck = []
        width_total = 543
        height_total = 278
        signs = ["clubs", "hearts", "spades", "diamonds"]
        row = -1
        with Image.open("playing_cards.png") as card_img:
            for i in range(4):
                row += 1
                for j in range(13):
                    box = (width_total / 13 * j, height_total / 4 * i, width_total / 13 * (j + 1), height_total / 4 * (i + 1))
                    card_img.crop(box).save("{j}_{i}.png".format(j = j, i = i))
                    deck.append(Card(j, signs[i], "{j}_{i}.png".format(j = j, i= i), "ready"))
        return deck
        
    def mix_deck(self, deck):
        return sample(deck, len(deck))

    def give_cards(self):
        remaining_deck = self.mix_deck(self.make_deck())
        main_deck = []
        player_decks = {}
        for name in self.players:
            if player_decks.get(name) is None:
                cards = []
                for i in range(5):
                    cards.append(remaining_deck.pop())
                player_decks[name] = cards
        main_deck.append(remaining_deck.pop())
        self.main_deck, self.remaining_deck, self.player_decks = main_deck, remaining_deck, player_decks

    def get_curent_player(self):
        self.round += 1
        self.curent_player = self.players[(round - 1) % len(self.players)]

    def put_cards(self):
        for player, deck in self.player_decks.items():
            for card in deck:
                if card.status == "selected":
                    self.main_deck.append(card)
                    self.player_decks[player].remove(card)
            
                if card.num == 2:
                    self.card_debt += 2
                if card.num == 3:
                    self.card_debt += 3
                if card.num == 4:
                    self.player_wait_times[player] = 0
                if card.num == 7:
                    self.card_debt = 0
                    self.player_wait_times[player] = 0
    
    def can_change_status(self, card):
        return True

    def change_card_status(self, coordonates):
        for player, deck in self.player_decks.items():
            new_cards = []
            for card in deck:
                if coordonates[0] > card.coordonates[0] and coordonates[0] < card.coordonates[0] + card.img_width and coordonates[1] > card.coordonates[1] and coordonates[1] < card.coordonates[1] + card.img_height:
                    if card.status == "ready":
                        if self.can_change_status(card):
                            card.status = "selected"
                            print(card.status)
                    elif card.status == "selected":
                        card.status = "ready"
                        print(card.status)
                new_cards.append(card)
            self.player_decks[player] = new_cards
```

"playing_cards.png":
!
["playing_cards.png"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3G2ex.png)

This is how it looks now:

[image: This is how it looks now]

This is how I would want it to look, no card down below after clicking on it:

[image: desired]

Comment: You don't clear the screen for each frame.

Comment: Well....... How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The card gets duplicated because you aren't clearing the screen within each frame, so the previous frames still appear. In pygame, we can clear the screen by using the `fill` function. We use the fill function like this: `screen.fill((0, 0, 0))` (this fills the screen with the color black and also hides the previous frames). If you add that to your game loop, the card won't get duplicated.

### Change your game loop to this:

```
while True:
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0)) # You can change this to the color of your choice
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1:
            game.change_card_status(pygame.mouse.get_pos())
    
    card_count = 0
    for player, deck in game.player_decks.items():
        new_cards = []
        for card in deck:
            card_image = pygame.image.load(card.img)
            card.make_coordonates((50 * card_count + 500, 500))
            if card.status == "selected":
                card.coordonates[1] -= 100
            new_cards.append(card)
            card_count += 1
        game.player_decks[player] = new_cards

    for player, deck in game.player_decks.items():
        for card in deck:
            display_card(card)
    pygame.display.update()
```